# How to filter logs by thread name when using logback?

Tags: spring-boot, filter, logback

I want to output the log of the scheduled task separately to the specified log file.
But the following code doesn't work.The "FILE" appender always contains scheduling log.

Java Version:8

SpringBoot Version: 2.2.6.RELEASE

Logback Version: 1.2.3

The Filter class:

```
public class ThreadFilter extends Filter<ILoggingEvent> {

    public static final String SCHEDULING = "scheduling";

    @Override
    public FilterReply decide(ILoggingEvent iLoggingEvent) {
        return StringUtils.contains(iLoggingEvent.getThreadName(), SCHEDULING)
                ? FilterReply.ACCEPT
                : FilterReply.DENY;
    }
}
```

The logback-spring.xml config:

```
 <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="com.sample.ThreadFilter"/>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_PATH}/${APP_NAME}_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>60</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>
    
    <appender name="TASK_FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <filter class="com.sample.ThreadFilter"/>
        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_FILE_PATH}/task_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.%i.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>30</maxHistory>
            <timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.SizeAndTimeBasedFNATP">
                <maxFileSize>10MB</maxFileSize>
            </timeBasedFileNamingAndTriggeringPolicy>
            <totalSizeCap>20GB</totalSizeCap>
        </rollingPolicy>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>${FILE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern>
        </encoder>

    </appender>
    
    <root>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="CONSOLE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="TASK_FILE"/>
    </root>
```

I want to output scheduling  task logs to "TASK_FILE", and other logs to "FILE".